# ExecuteNonQuery- Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am having an issue with an OleDb Connection to MS Access. This line is throwing the error :

`command1.ExecuteNonQuery();`

The next part is my code:

```
if (textBox.Text.Length != 6) return;
{
    cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT last_name +', '+ first_name from name where id =@Name");
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", textBox.Text.Replace(@"L", "")));
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = DBConnection;

    returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "\t " + textBox.Text.Replace(@"L", "");

    DBConnection.Close();

    OleDbConnection connection1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Registration.accdb");
    OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
    command1.CommandText = "UPDATE Table SET ID=@ID, Name=@Name, TimeIn=@TimeInAM, TimeOut=@TimeOutAM";
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", returnValue);
    connection1.Open();
    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection1.Close();

    Staff_Register(returnValue, e);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not associate `connection1` with `command1`, that is why you are getting the exception.

```
command1.CommandText = "UPDATE Table SET ID=@ID, Name=@Name, TimeIn=@TimeInAM, TimeOut=@TimeOutAM";
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", returnValue);
command1.Connection = connection1; // missing this
connection1.Open();
```

Also consider using [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) statement with connections and command that will ensure the disposal of connection object.

Answer (score 0):

assign connection object to your command object before calling ExecuteNonQuery() as below:

```
command1.Connection=connection1 ;
```